# VB.NET How can I stretch my Toolstrip on form resize

Tags: vb.net, forms, toolstrip

I am using a form to display documents. At the bottom I have a Toolstrip with 3 Labels and 3 buttons. When I resize the form the Toolstrip doesnt stretch along with the width of the form.
[image]

The left button should be on the left side of the form, not half way. I tried with anchors but it doesn't give the right results.

Comment: You have already asked this same question. The answer is still the same: the ToolStrip, by default, is docked to the Form, thus it resizes when the Form resizes. Just dock it to Bottom. Inside the Parent Form, that is.

Comment: @Jimi Sometimes learning means asking the same question again. The Toolstrip is docked to the form. I was just hoping to make it so that the left button and toolstrip label stayed on the left side of the form and stretch.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need a StatusStrip instead of a ToolStrip? A StatusStrip is usually placed at the Bottom and provides this behavior on its own. You just need to set the Labels' `Spring` Property to `true`. The `LayoutStyle` Property of the StatusStrip needs to be set to `Table` (which is the default anyway).

Comment: @Jimi I will give it a try with a StatusStrip